# How to put a dynamic custom attribute in HTML(PUG) in VueJS 2?

Tags: attributes, vuejs2, pug

I am using VueJs 2 with Pug and I have the following code:

```
.mb-3(v-for="(payments, index) in historyPayments" :key="index" no-body='')
  b-btn(variant="default" block='' href='#' v-b-toggle.accordion2016="") // I need to change accordion2016 using a dynamic variable
    | {{ index }}
```

In my iterator I have data that I would like to put as an attribute in an HTML tag.
The current attribute I have is: `v-b-toggle.accordion2016`, but I would like to change it to something like in the following code:

```
.mb-3(v-for="(payments, index) in historyPayments" :key="index" no-body='')
  b-btn(variant="default" block='' href='#' "`v-b-toggle.#{index}`"="")
    | {{ index }}
```

How could I change the attribute dynamically using Pug? I have tried but I get syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use v-bind like this:

```
v-bind="{ [`v-b-toggle.${index}`]: '' }"
```

By using ES6 template string syntax and single element array, you can bind a variable in an attribute. Finally you only need to use v-bind to bind attrs dinamically in components.

Answer (score 0):

You could use v-b-toggle to toggle a value and have your href as a computed value which is returned based on your toggled value

I.E:

```js
computed: {
  computedHref () {
    return toggledValue ? "first-href-link" : "second-href-link"
  }
}
```

And just use computedHref value in your href like so

b-btn(variant="default" block='' href='computedHref')

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap vue, then you can do it like this:

```
.mb-3(v-for="(payments, index) in historyPayments" :key="index" no-body)
  b-btn(variant="default" block href='#' v-b-toggle="`accordion${index}`")
    | {{ index }}
```